# How to interpret the Maximum flow path length raster, from the SAGA Maximum flow path length tool

Tags: qgis, saga, hydrology

Does anyone know how to interpret the Maximum flow path length raster, after running the SAGA Maximum flow path length tool?

I have used this tool and received a raster but I'm not sure how I can get the maximum flow length (possibly as a line or even just a number) for this catchment. The raster values vary from 0 to 139. But I'm sure the flow path should be of order of 600-700 feet. I attached the output result if it helps.

As input, I just had the filled elevation raster.

[image][image]

Comment: Which CRS are you working in?

Comment: It is 'EPSG:2284 - NAD83 / Virginia South (ftUS) - Projected', Unit: Feet

Comment: Could it be number of pixels?

Comment: You can visually check it by overlaying watershed polygons (plus stream lines, if you like). Please give it a try! If I can assume those cars(?) as the "yardstick", the legend looks okay.